General relativity and velocity of light
Let us consider a generic metric: $$ds^2 = g_{00}c^2dt^2 + g_{0i}cdx^idt + g_{ij}dx^idx^j$$
I wish to find the speed of light in a particular direction $x^i$, say with $i=2$.
For light, the proper distance is $ds=0$. This gives:
$$0 = g_{00}c^2dt^2 + g_{0i}cdx^idt + g_{ij}dx^idx^j$$
I can rewrite this as:
$$-g_{00}c^2dt^2 = g_{0i}cdx^idt + g_{ij}dx^idx^j$$
Now, can I say that the velocity of light in said direction is:
$$\sqrt{\left ( \frac{dx^2}{dt^2}\right )^2} = \sqrt{\frac{-c^2 g_{00}}{g_{22}}}$$
Is this the right answer?
Note: the other metric components, say $g_{2i}$ are not zero.
If not, then how do I go about it?

see here for a few examples with and without crossterms

Set $dx^1 = dx^3=0$ in the metric equation, and divide the whole thing by $(dt)^2$. What will result is a quadratic equation in $v^2 = dx^2/dt$, which you can then solve using the quadratic formula. If $g_{02} \neq 0$, this will result in the (coordinate) speed of light being different in the positive and negative $y$-directions.

If $g_{02} \ne 0$, then I get the quadratic equation $c^2 g_{00} + g_{22} v^2 + g_{02} v = 0$, where $v = \frac{dx^2}{dt}$. Is this the quadratic equation you mention?

@Angela:  Yes, it should be something like that.
